# Start a subclass level from superclass

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm learning to use Cocos2d for iOS, in particular I am working on an iPhone's app.
I created a superclass called `basicLevel` where i set all I need for every level I'm going to create. Of course, the levels I'm going to create will be subclasses of `basicLevel`.
In `basicLevel` there is a CCMenu that contains a CCMenuItemImage called `startButton`. What I want to do is that when I touch that button the subclass level start. For example in the first level I'm creating, there is a timer and I want that this timer start only when `startButton` is touched.

Thank you.

Comment: Tip: classes are supposed to start with an uppercase letter (BasicLevel) to differentiate them from methods and properties which are supposed to start with a lowercase letter. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingBasics.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method in the base class (`basicLevel`) that is called whenever the menu button you want is pressed:

```
- (void)startLevel;
```

Then override this method on all classes that derive from `basicLevel`.

Comment: @user2270069 : upvote if the answer is useful, and accept it if it is the best answer to your question. ie. thank you :)